# Novel about people so average/boring that they are effectively invisible

Tags: story-identification

This was a novel I read over 20 years ago. Unsure of the publication date, I think it was then current (late 1990s). The protagonist is a young man, a boring one with a boring office job... girlfriend leaves him because of him being boring. He comes to realize that no one notices him when he sees an older man like him waltz out of a convenience store with a case of beer unnoticed. He starts experimenting, discovering that he can get away with nearly any crime.

Eventually he reunites with his girlfriend, who has the same superpower. Things quickly get really weird (as if they weren't already) when him and just a couple of others are actually exceptionally boring and become invisible even to the others like themselves. Something about the Great God Pan at the end (an Arthur Machen thing, if I'm not mistake).

Comment: Sounds a little like Neverwhere by Neil Gaiman (1996) although it's been too long since I read it to be sure.

Comment: It sounds like a similar premise to "Are you listening?" by Harlan Ellison, but a rather different plot.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 - In Neverwhere the people who're invisible are the homeless and crazy. Gaiman was making a statement about how those in the city above (e.g. us) ignore people from the city below. Literally they become invisible.

Comment: I seem to recall this book/series as well, but I can't seem to find it with Google.

Comment: Similar concept to The Janitor in Space by Amber Sparks, and "Glyph" in The Ballad of Halo Jones, by Alan Moore and Ian Gibson.

Comment: [So mundane or boring they are invisible is a well-trod trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheNondescript).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly *To See The Invisible Man* by Robert Silverberg.

Adapted as [an episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_See_the_Invisible_Man) of The Twilight Zone.  I've seen the TV version, but not the original story.

Also somewhat similar to the invisible boy story in the collection [Temps](http://popculture-shop.blogspot.com/2010/11/neil-gaiman-temps-book-novel-prose.html). Featuring a young man who nobody notices or pays any attention to. He can walk into the middle of a robbery and take the criminals guns away from them, and they completely ignore him.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_See_the_Invisible_Man -- the title character was only "invisible" in the sense that everyone else knew they were *supposed* to ignore him as a matter of law. It wasn't that they never noticed his presence in the first place.